# Example of a connected, finite simplicial complex that is not a closed surface

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

I need to find an example of a connected finite SC that is not a closed combinatorial surface, but satisfying 1. contains only 0 1 2 simplices 2. every 1-simplex is a face of precisely two 2-simplices 3. every point of |K| lies in a 2 simplex.

The first example I came out with is tetrahedron. But I think it is a closed surface. Should I delete some point to make it not closed?

Comment: If you delete a point, it won't be a simplicial complex.

Comment: I am also curious to find out whether it is possible to find such a simplicial complex. I have been trying to find complexes where there is a vertex whose link is not a simplicial circle, so then its star isn't homeomorphic to the open disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so then the complex isn't a 2-manifold. I haven't had any success yet.

Answer (score 2):

Take a triangulation of the sphere with a lot of triangles in it. Then glue two of the vertices together in such a way that the result is still a simplicial complex. This can't be done for the tetrahedron since every pair of vertices share an edge, but is possible for larger triangulations.

Comment: How to glue two vertices in a triangulation of the sphere? Why the result is not a closed combinatorial surface?

Comment: @Kenneth.K By "glue" I mean form the quotient space. It's not a surface because no neighborhood of the glued point is homeomorphic to an open disk. You can see this by noting that any sufficiently small neighborhood can be disconnected by removing the point, whereas in a disk no point can be removed to make it disconnected.

Comment: @Kenneth.K or, even easier, you could just note that the link of the given vertex is a disjoint union of two circles.

Answer (score 1):

Take two tetrahedrons and join them on a vertex. The link of the join is then a union of two disjoint simplicial circles, or alternatively, any neighbourhood of the join can be disconnected by removing the point of the join, whereas there exists no open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that can be disconnected by removing a single point.

More specifically, consider the topological realisation of the following abstract simplicial complex $(V, \Sigma)$

$
V = \{\ 0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13\ \}
$

$
\Sigma =  \wp(\{\ 0, 1, 2, 3\ \}) \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \cup \ \wp(\{\ 11, 12, 13\ \}) \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \cup \ \{\{\ 0, 11\ \},\{\ 0, 12\ \},\{\ 0, 13\ \},\{\ 0, 11, 12\ \},\{\ 0, 11, 13\ \},\{\ 0, 12, 13\ \}\}
$